# How do I inject constants with hk2 in jersey 2.0?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

How do I inject a constant into some class using HK2 in jersey? With Guice I could have some class like

```
public class DependsOnFoo {

    @Inject
    public DependsOnFoo(@Named("FOO") String foo) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and I would configure it in the injector with something like

```
bind(String.class).named("FOO").toInstance(new String("foo"))
```

What's the equivalent, if any, in HK2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm in the process of learning hk2 coming from Guice. Honestly I am still in the weeds a little with the complexity of hk2 vs the simplicity of guice. I did find this solution to work for me and it is much similar to the Guice builder. This did seem a little more straight forward than having to use the `ServiceLocatorUtilities`class.

```
public class IOCMockRestModule extends AbstractBinder
    bind(20000).to(Integer.class).named("MAX_REQUEST_TIMEOUT");
}
```

And to use the injected value:

```
@Inject
protected CustomerResource(ICustomerProvider customerProvider, @Named("MAX_REQUEST_TIMEOUT") int maxTimeoutMillis) {
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in a more flexible way that doesn't require a new `bind()` for each new named value such as `MAX_REQUEST_TIMEOUT`? I'm hoping something more flexible is possible where the named value can be read at runtime and looked via custom implementation such as from a properties file, environment variable, etc?

Comment: I don't think hk2 has this functionality but you could look at guice's com.google.inject.name.Names.bindProperties(Binder binder, Properties properties) as a guide to create your own. It should be pretty straight forward I think to port this functionality to hk2.

Comment: That's helpful thanks @Chris. Since I wanted to stick to HK2 and not introduce another technology I ended up successfully using a custom annotation and InjectionResolver  to get the behavior I wanted as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436316/5661065