# Using a custom hk2 InjectionResolver to inject application configuration

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

Kind of a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26365077/6069). I'm trying to inject application configuration data using JSR-330 standard annotations and the HK2 framework bundled with jersey.

Ideally I'd like to create a custom `InjectionResolver` for the `Named` annotation, which will lookup the desired values in a `Map` or `Properties` object that I will populate from data read elsewhere. In my first attempt I've created an `Application` instance like

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    ...
    packages(MY_PACKAGES);
    property(MY_CONFIG_PROPERTY, someValue);
    register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(ConfigurationInjectionResolver.class)
            .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Named>>(){})
            .in(Singleton.class)
        }
    });
}
```

and then my `InjectionResolver` looks like

```
public class ConfigurationInjectionResolver implements InjectionResolver<Named> {
    @Context Application application;

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> serviceHandle) {
        // lookup data in application.getProperties();
    }
}
```

My problem is that `application.getProperties()` is empty. Any idea what's wrong? Also, could I bind an instance of my Injector instead of binding the class? That way I could construct the instance passing my `Map` data as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "My problem is that application.getProperties() is empty. Any idea what's wrong?

No. This actually works perfectly fine for me.

```
public class ConfigurationInjectionResolver implements InjectionResolver<Named> {  
    @Context
    Application application;

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root) {
        Named annotation = injectee.getParent().getAnnotation(Named.class);
        Map<String, Object> props = application.getProperties();
        String name = annotation.value();
        System.out.println(props.get(name));
        return props.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() { return false; }
    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() { return false; }  
}

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        packages("jersey.startup.test");
        property("hello.config", "Hello World Property");
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(ConfigurationInjectionResolver.class)
                        .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Named>>() {
                        }).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Resource

```
@Path("/config")
public class ConfigResource {

    @Named("hello.config")
    String hello;

    @GET
    public Response getHello() {
        return Response.ok(hello).build();
    }
}
```

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/test/rest/config`
>   `Hello World Property`

Personally though, in this situation, I would create my own annotation, as to not override any existing functionality of the `@Named` annotation.

---

### Another cool option

HK2 has a configuration extension, where you can load a `Properties` object from say a `.properties` file and and have those properties automatically injected with the `@Configured` annotation. I couldn't find any documentation on this, but there is an example usage of it in the [HK2 source code examples](https://github.com/hk2-project/hk2/tree/master/examples/configuration).

Here's an example implementation

Required dependencies. Check the Jersey version and see what HK2 version it depends on. In my case Jersey 2.13 uses HK2 2.3.0-b10, so that should be the `${hk2.version}`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-configuration-hub</artifactId>
    <version>${hk2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-configuration-integration</artifactId>
    <version>${hk2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-property-file</artifactId>
    <version>${hk2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

App config

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyApplication(ServiceLocator locator) {
        packages("jersey.startup.test");
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(locator, ConfigResource.class);
        try {
            loadConfigurationProperties(locator);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JerseyApplication.class.getName())
                                   .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void loadConfigurationProperties(ServiceLocator locator) 
                                                 throws IOException {
        ConfigurationUtilities.enableConfigurationSystem(locator);
        PropertyFileUtilities.enablePropertyFileService(locator);
        PropertyFileService propertyFileService 
                = locator.getService(PropertyFileService.class);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/configuration.properties");
        props.load(url.openStream());
        PropertyFileHandle propertyFileHandle 
                = propertyFileService.createPropertyHandleOfAnyType();
        propertyFileHandle.readProperties(props);
    }
}
```

`configuration.properties`

```
AppConfiguration.App.hello=Hello Squirrel Property!
```

Resource

```
@Path("/config")
@ConfiguredBy("AppConfiguration")
public class ConfigResource {

    @Configured
    String hello;

    @GET
    public Response getHello() {
        return Response.ok(hello).build();
    }
}
```

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/test/rest/config`
>   `Hello Squirrel Property!`

**Diclaimer:** Since this feature isn't well documented, I am not sure if I have a good implementation here. It is just by trial and error. For instance this

```
ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(locator, ConfigResource.class);
```

I feel shouldn't be necessary. It seems redundant, as I am already package scanning. So to explicitly add the `ConfigResource` to the locator context doesn't seem right to me.